# IP Address classes and designation in python

Tags: python, arrays, class, ip

can anyone help me to solve this question?
I need to make an IP Address classifier that shows the class and Designation of it
example:
Class: A, Designation: Special
I tried this but didn't complete it please don't judge I'm such a beginner

```
ip=input("please enter an IP address:")
chap=ip.split('.')
q='.'
address=chap[0]
print(address)

#classes
ClassA= range(0,127)
ClassB= range(128,191)
ClassC= range(192,223)
ClassD= range(224,239)
ClassE= range(240,255)
if address in ClassA:
    print("Class A")
elif address in ClassB:
    print("Class B")
elif address in ClassC:
    print("Class C")
elif address in ClassD:
    print("Class D")
elif address in ClassE:
    print("Class E")
```

Comment: `address` is a *string* because it is an element of the list returned by `split()`. But you are comparing that string to a `range` which is a bunch of integers. Do `address=int(chap[0])`.

Comment: Classful networking was **obsoleted in 1993** by CIDR, nearly 30 years ago. Please leave it dead and buried.